# Microsoft Compression Folder settings

Tags: compression, zip

My company has restricted use of PKzip in favor of the Microsoft Compression Folder. Is there a way to split large zip files similar to other commercial zip applications?

We use zip more for archiving (collecting batches of files for distribution) than compression. If this is not possible I will need to submit an exception request for approval to purchase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to split large zip files similar to other commercial
>   zip applications?

There isn't a method to split the archive created by the built-in (Compressed zipped Folder) feature in any version of Windows.  In order to create a archive that has multiple parts third-party software must be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [7z / 7zip](http://www.7-zip.org).

- Use right click on the file that you want to split and select the option 7z -> Add to archive...
- Select your favorite file format, like Zip.
- Write the maximun size of a part in the textbox of split the file. (Example: "5M" for parts of 5 MB, 4G for 4GB) - Click on Acept